# What do you greet in German when someone gets something new

Tags: word-choice

In my mother language, Hebrew, there is a greeting especially for cases when someone gets or buys something new: תתחדש (according to Google Translate: "Resumes" or "be renewed"). Is there something similar in German? If not, what will you say to someone who, for example, just got a haircut or bought a new car?

Comment: I think we need to know what "תתחדש" means.

Comment: Google translate says תתחדש means "resume". If that is right, how to interpret it?

Comment: I would have translated it literally more like: *"Wieder auf ein Neues"* but this can not be used in the same context in German.

Comment: If someone got a haircut, my usual response is "Do you need a good lawyer?", "Which profession has your hairdresser?" or "Don't worry, it will grow again..."

Comment: Alter Kack im neuen Frack. :) No pun intendet.

Comment: A modern -but more general (=not only for new things)-  option could be: *Cool* like *Cooles Auto*. In Arabic there would have been special and local expressions.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The usual case in German would be to just say something positive about the new acquaintance like e.g.

> *"Oh, schöne Frisur hast Du heute." - "Deine neue Frisur steht Dir ausgesprochen gut."*
>   *"Das ist aber ein schickes Auto!"*

Or we put it in a question:

> *"Ist die Jacke neu?"* - *"Warst Du beim Friseur?"*

There is not a **common** expression for this. But we do sometimes hear a proverb in that context:

> *"Alles neu macht der Mai!"*

This is a quote from a traditional song by [Adam v. Kamp](http://www.volksliederarchiv.de/text1465.html) (1818) but it is a bit outdated and not so widely used.

Answer (score 3):

You probably recognize the new purchase/acquisition with a cheerful question like:

"Neues Auto?",
"Neue Frisur?",
"Neuer Laptop?",
"Neue Frau?"

Comment: You should not use "Neue Frau", unless You know exactly that Your company can handle that remark ;)

Comment: Would the question "neue Frau?" also be used upon seeing a man with a new haircut?